# Which IPs should I whitelist for a MySQL remote connection?

Tags: php, mysql, ip, cpanel, remote-access

I am trying to remotely connect to SQL from another website. I did a whois lookup to get the IP address of the domain that's trying to connect and whitelisted it in cPanel. I also did a `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` and got a different IP address for some reason, so I whitelisted that as well. I also tried whitelisting by the domain name but MySQL is still refusing the connection.

If I allow access from all (%) it will work, but obviously I'm not gonna do that.. How can I find out for sure, which IP address needs to be whitelisted in order for SQL to allow the connection?

Comment: Look in your cPanel of the site that will be connecting.  It will show you the IP Address, and that is the address you need to whitelist.  Additionally, when you say whitelist, be sure you mean to allow *remote connections* in your mysql (through cPanel).

Comment: See, thing is, I don't have cPanel access to the website that is connecting, only to the site that has the DB I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: Have you tried allowing remote mysql connections on the target DB cPanel, to which you have access? Have you also tried whitelisting the URL instead of the IP address? Some web hosting services share a common IP address for several URLs and use the received URL to identify which resources within their system to point to.

Comment: @NachtBlaad That was it, I didn't know the receiving server had to be whitelisted as well.. If you put it in an answer I will check it.

Comment: @Adelphia I would love to, but cale_b gave the same solution first. I just rephrased it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to white-list the main IP of the server (on where the domain is hosted). The outgoing connection from the server goes via primary IP address of the server. If it's a Linux machine you can use the command `hostname -i` to find out the primary IP address. Also you can check which IP is establishing connection to the MySQL using the command `tcpdump -n dst 1.1.1.1 and port 3306`
Change the port number & IP address according to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis for problem it more easy but it needs some work.

Access to console mysql for verify if Cpanel interface put correct credentials on mysql. After all WHM / Cpanel is simply a control panel that makes administration work for us, and therefore is susceptible to bugs

```
mysql > SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE %user%;
+--------------------+----------------+
| user               | host           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| special_user       | %              |
| horde              | 127.0.0.1      |
| zabbix             | 127.0.0.1      |
| mysqlbackup        | 163.XXX.XXX.31 |
| root               | 176.XX.XXX.39  |
...
```

If user it's on mysql privilege tables, verify if my.cnf it's configured for access remotly

if exists must be 0.0.0.0

```
cat /etc/my.cnf |grep bind-address
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Also `skip-networking` can't be on /etc/my.cnf

**Check firewall** for accesss to 3306 port

```
iptables -L -n |grep 3306
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:3306
```

It is also good to help, to indicate the error that showed the application as this determines the layer where the fault occurred.

**Example**

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host ‘1.2.3.4’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

**And logs of mysql**

cat /var/lib/mysql/[hostname].err 
2016-04-06  0:26:19 140080907868928 [Warning] IP address '23.251.55.75' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

All paths examples are for WHM/Cpanel server.

[text] substitution for real name

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I figured out that there was an incorrect `password` entry in the `mysql.user` table.

What I had done was added an incorrect password for a correct host. I was able to identify the incorrect password by looking at the `password` field - the only password that was different belonged to this host I wanted to connect from.

`SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE '%username%' \G;`

I deleted the entry and assigned the privileges again and the issue was fixed.

It was dev environment where I did the changes at MySQL level.